# Select a wireless network in an iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi

I'm trying to build an iPad app that has the ability to connect to a Wi-Fi network.

Essentially I want to bring up a pop-up to display a list of available networks if one is not detected.

I have downloaded Mocha Telnet lite which is able to do exactly this.

Are there any inbuilt commands in the iOS SDK that enable interaction with the Wi-Fi networks?